# Asking rsync to exclude /mnt /proc etc... when transfering the entire root filesystem for backup to /mnt ignores the excludes

Tags: debian, rsync, backup

I've been trying to use all kinds of rsync commands in different kinds of constellations similar to [this one on the arch page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/rsync#Full_system_backup) to back up my linux system to an SMB Storage.

this includes the following versions:

1. `rsync -aAXv --exclude=/dev/ --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/cdrom/* --exclude=/lost+found / /mnt/mounted_smb_storage`
2. `rsync -aAXHv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /mnt/mounted_smb_storage`
3. `rsync -aAXHv --exclude-from=/path/to/excludelist.txt / /mnt/mounted_smb_storage`

both with and without quotations...

It always seems to ignore the --exclude command as long as I use the Root Directory as source. Once I use a source like `/mnt` and use `--exclude /mnt/*` it ignores the directory like it's supposed to

Im using Debian 11 and rsync version 3.2.3  protocol version 31

Comment: I can't reproduce this (with a different version of rsync), but you're looking for the `-x` option.

Comment: rsync -aAXv --exclude={mnt,proc} /* /mnt/mounted_smb_storage

Comment: Using rsync-3.2.4 regularly -aXH --del with root dir as source + an exclude list of the kind you wrote in your § 2. Everything is systematically fine. Are you sure that when launching your §2 command, your mounted_smb_storage did not already contained the files from your exclude list ? (having tried in all constellations… such a mistake could be possible ;-) Additionally your last paragraph puzzles me : You do realize that excluding /mnt/* won't ignore the directory. Only the files laying behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling `rsync` with `apt purge rsync`.

`rsync` had a weird dependency to a `maria-db` package when uninstalling

After reinstalling `rsync` alone the commands work as expected again..

Answer (score 0):

You could marginally better write this as

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude=/dev/ --exclude=/proc/ --exclude=/sys/ --exclude=/tmp/ --exclude=/run/ --exclude=/mnt/ --exclude=/media/ --exclude=/cdrom/ --exclude=lost+found/ / /mnt/mounted_smb_storage
```

Or with a shell that understands brace expansion,

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude=/{dev,proc,sys,tmp,run,mnt,media,cdrom}/ --exclude=lost+found/ / /mnt/mounted_smb_storage
```

The trailing `/` on each exclusion indicates to `rsync` that the item is a directory. The leading `/` ties each to the top of the source path. The excluded directories themselves will also be omitted from the copy.

Better still, if your SMB storage server allows you to run `rsync` you could gain efficiencies on subsequent copies by using a network copy. For example,

```
 rsync -aAXv --exclude=/{dev,proc,sys,tmp,run,mnt,media,cdrom}/ --exclude=lost+found/ / user@storageServer:/mnt/mounted_smb_storage
```

For non-root accounts on such a destination you might need to add `-M--fake-super` both for backups and restores, so that metadata attributes such as ownership can be recorded alongside each target file.